How to extract elements from an array-column based on their lengths in PySpark?
I have a PySpark DataFrame with one array column. Each array contains string elements. I need to extract those elements that have a specific length.



id
array_with_strings




00001
[N, NS, NSY, NSB]


00002
[B, BS, BSNY, BSD]



I am aiming for this:



id
twoDigits




00001
NS


00002
BS



I tried:
def getTwoDigits(arr):
        for x in arr:
            if F.length(x) == 2:
                return x
            else:
                return None
extractTwoDigits_udf = F.udf(lambda z: getTwoDigits(z))

df = df.withColumn(
        "twoDigits", extractTwoDigits_udf(F.col("array_with_strings"))
    )

I am not sure what I should use in this specific instance.
Thanks in advance for any help or hints.

use the  filter function: df.selectExpr("id", "explode(filter(array_with_strings, x -> length(x)=2)) as twoDigits")

Try the below code. :
df=df.withColumn("exploded",explode(col("array_with_strings")))
df=df.withColumn("len",length(col("exploded")))
df1=df.filter(col("len")==2)
df1.show()


You need to update the UDF as follows:
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def getTwoDigits(arr):
    for x in arr:
        if len(x) == 2:
            return x
    return None

extractTwoDigits_udf = F.udf(getTwoDigits, StringType())

df = df.withColumn("twoDigits", extractTwoDigits_udf(F.col("array_with_strings")))

df.show(truncate=False)

# +-----+---------+
# |id   |twoDigits|
# +-----+---------+
# |00001|NS       |
# |00002|BS       |
# +-----+---------+

But I would recommend you avoid UDFs whenever possible. Instead, use expr as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
    ("00001", ["N", "NS", "NSY", "NSB"]),
    ("00002", ["B", "BS", "BSNY", "BSD"])
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "array_with_strings"])

df = df.withColumn(
    "twoDigits",
    expr("filter(array_with_strings, x -> length(x) = 2)[0]")
)

df.select("id", "twoDigits").show(truncate=False)

# +-----+---------+
# |id   |twoDigits|
# +-----+---------+
# |00001|NS       |
# |00002|BS       |
# +-----+---------+

